# Want naked links across files

Tags: hyperref, links, xr

I compile via `pdflatex f01.tex`. My preamble normally contains

```
...
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Suppose that I have `f01.tex` and `f02.tex` in the same directory, and (for example) `f01.tex` contains

```
\begin{enumerate}...

\item \label{item-x002}%
...

\end{enumerate}
```

Then I can refer to the `item-x002` link in `f02.tex` by placing the following
at the end of the preamble to `f02.tex`:

```
\externaldocument[f01-]{f01}
```

I can then place the following link in `f02.tex`:

```
\ref{f01-item-x002}
```

Furthermore, the `hyperref` package allows **naked** linking (outside of any
section or environment) within a document as follows:

```
\hypertarget{naked-link}{This is my naked label.}
...
\hyperlink{naked-link}{This is my naked link.}
```

**However,** I can't find a way to (functionally) combine the two methods.  I want to place a naked link in `f01.tex`, and dynamically refer to it in `f02.tex`.  I do
**not** want to *open* `f01.pdf`, and I do **not** care if the link is *clickable*.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Your request seems contradictory. Why would you not care if the link is clickable... it's obviously paramount for a "naked link" to be clickable, otherwise it would be worthless.

Comment: @Werner No, the request is not contradictory.  I create pdf files of solutions to various problems (e.g. real_analysis_01.pdf, complex_analysis_01.pdf).  In each pdf, I manually create a table of contents, rather than using the canned features, so that I can imbed inline math directly into the table of contents entry.  CONTINUED ON NEXT COMMENT.

Comment: @Werner A specific problem will begin like \label{x001}, without any sectioning or other type of environment.  This is useful for having my manually constructed table of contents return the page that this label is on.  If I can have the second file contain a link that I have formatted by real_analysis_01(\ref{x001}), then I can glance at the first file's table of contents to see if I wish to review the problem.  I normally use qpdfview to keep several pdf-s open simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fake this cross-document `\hypertarget`-`\hyperlink` by using `\phantomsection\label`-`\hyperref`:

- `f01.tex`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \begin{document}

  \phantomsection\label{naked-link}%
  This is my naked label.

  \end{document}
  ```

  `\phantomsection` sets an appropriate hyper target for any future `\label`. In this case it's needed since the link is set to be "naked."
- `f02.tex`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{xr-hyper}
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \begin{document}

  \externaldocument[f01-]{f01}

  \hyperref[f01-naked-link]{This is my naked link.}

  \end{document}
  ```

  `\hyperref[<ref>]{<stuff>}` sets a "naked" link to an internal (or external) `<ref>`erence.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks very much.  I had already tried \phantomsection, but I never thought to couple it with \hyperref.